# The included URLconf "" does not appear to have any pattern in it

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have looked at other answers to this question, but i still can't figure out what's wrong.
Indeed, my projects works on Ubuntu and Fedora but I have to deploy my script on a Debian and that's where I get the error message

```
>Exception in thread django-main-thread:
>Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "/var/rails/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 581, in url_patterns
>    iter(patterns)
>TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable
>
>During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
>Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
>    self.run()
>  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
>    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
>  File "/var/rails/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
>    fn(*args, **kwargs)
>  File "/var/rails/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
>    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
>  File "/var/rails/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
>    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
>  File "/var/rails/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
>    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
>  File "/var/rails/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
>    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
>  File "/var/rails/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
>    return check_resolver(resolver)
>  File "/var/rails/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
>    return check_method()
>  File "/var/rails/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in check
>    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
>  File "/var/rails/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
>    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
>  File "/var/rails/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
>    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
>django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'compare.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

My compare.urls

```py
"""compare URL Configuration
The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include("comparison.urls")),
    path('comparison/', include('comparison.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

and my comparison.urls (app)

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('comparison/', views.viewResults ,name='results'),
    path('',views.home, name = "home"),
]
```

Following comment, I add

views :

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from comparison.models import *
import test4
# Create your views here.

def viewResults(request):
    test4.main()
    listImport = []
    listExport = []
    listCompare = []
    listSave = []
    listExportFP = []
    listFile = []
    listFolder = test4.listU
    path_name = test4.path_name
    for i in range(len(ImportError.objects.all())):
        a = ImportError.objects.all()[i].fileError
        b = ImportError.objects.all()[i].value
        c = ImportError.objects.all()[i].dateError
        d = ImportError.objects.all()[i].durationError
        listImport.append([a,b,c,d,listFolder[i]])
    for i in range(len(CompareError.objects.all())):
        e = CompareError.objects.all()[i].fileError
        f = CompareError.objects.all()[i].value
        g = CompareError.objects.all()[i].dateError
        h = CompareError.objects.all()[i].durationError
        listCompare.append([e,f,g,h])
    for i in range(len(ExportError.objects.all())):
        j = ExportError.objects.all()[i].fileError
        k = ExportError.objects.all()[i].value
        l = ExportError.objects.all()[i].dateError
        m = ExportError.objects.all()[i].durationError
        listExport.append([j,k,l,m])
    for i in range(len(ExportFerosPdsError.objects.all())):
        n = ExportFerosPdsError.objects.all()[i].fileError
        o = ExportFerosPdsError.objects.all()[i].value
        p = ExportFerosPdsError.objects.all()[i].dateError
        q = ExportFerosPdsError.objects.all()[i].durationError
        listExportFP.append([n,o,p,q])
    for i in range(len(SaveError.objects.all())):
        r = SaveError.objects.all()[i].fileError
        s = SaveError.objects.all()[i].value
        t = SaveError.objects.all()[i].dateError
        u = SaveError.objects.all()[i].durationError
        listSave.append([r,s,t,u])  
    listImport = sorted(listImport) 
    listSave = sorted(listSave)
    listCompare = sorted(listCompare)
    listExport = sorted(listExport)
    listExportFP = sorted(listExportFP)
    for i in range(len(ImportError.objects.all())):
        listFile.append([listImport[i],listCompare[i],listExport[i],listExportFP[i],listSave[i]])
    return render(request, 'comparison/results.html', locals())



def home(request):
    return render(request, 'comparison/home.html', locals())
```

And Here are the imports of my test4

```py
import os
import openpyxl as op
import random as rd
import shutil as sh
import datetime as dt
import shutil as sh
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
from openpyxl.styles import colors
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color
import pyexcel as p
import time
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
import pyautogui
from comparison.models import *
```

When I comment "import pyautogui" script seems to work.
But I need this library.

Thanks to help me

Comment: As the error mentions : "If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import." => did you check this ?

Comment: have you installed all requirements? `pip install -r requirements/dev.txt`

Comment: Yes I checked, even PyAutoGUI